# Unit test object construction that raises ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class which raises `ValueError` for a non-existent file path constructor parameter and I'd like to test it.

```
import os
import os.path


class MetricsManager:


    def __init__(self, reference_file_path, translations_file_path):
        if not os.path.isfile(reference_file_path):
            raise ValueError(f'{reference_file_path} does not exist.')

        if not os.path.isfile(translations_file_path):
            raise ValueError(f'{translations_file_path} does not exist')

        self._references_file_path = reference_file_path
        self.translations_file_path = translations_file_path
```

But my test below fails.

```
import unittest
from src.metrics_manager import MetricsManager


def create_instance():
    x = MetricsManager('foo.txt', 'bar.txt')


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, create_instance())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: How do you know about `assertRaises()`? What did you read about it in the documentation?

Comment: `"and I'd like to test it."` Phrase heard all too infrequently in the world of programmers.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have the `assertRaises()` call coded properly:

```
self.assertRaises(ValueError, MetricsManager, 'foo.txt', 'bar.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

`assertRaises` takes the function to be called as an argument, not the return value from actually calling it.

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, create_instance)
```

If you call it first, the exception occurs before `assertRaises` gets called. You have to let `assertRaises` make the actual call.

You can also use `assertRaises` in a `with` statement:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            create_instance()
```

Here, you *do* call `create_instance` yourself, because any exception raised inside the `with` statement is implicitly caught and passed to the context manager's `__exit__` method.